# I get a empty post after sumbit:php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I add with jquery inputs according to the value of the input I make on it an action onchange.
my problem is when I open my DB I find all the fields I fill it except the field I add it with html "schools_name"...

my js :

```
jQuery('#ecoles_number').on('change', function() {
        i_var = jQuery("#ecoles_number").val();
        //alert (i_var);
        for (var i = 0; i < i_var; i++) {
            jQuery("#mairie_div_nom").prepend("Nom du l'ecole: <br> <input type='text' name='ecoles_name' value='' required><br>");
            }
});
```

my code :

```
 if (!empty($_POST['Submit_mairie'] ) ){


        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $nom_mairie = $_POST["nom_mairie"];
        $ecoles = $_POST["ecoles"];
        $total_eleve = $_POST["total"];
        $ecoles_name = '"'.implode(',', $_POST["ecoles_name"]).'"';

        $checkbox_val= "le nombres totales du ecoles est "
                .$_POST["ecoles"].
                ",le nombres totales du classes est "
                . $_POST["classes"].
                ",le nombres totales du eleves est "
                .$_POST["total"]."";


                //$checkbox_values = '"'.implode(',', $checkbox_val.'"';


            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->insert('wp_mairie_details', array(
                    'nom_mairie' => $nom_mairie,
                    'ecoles' => $ecoles,
                    'ecoles_name' => $ecoles_name,
                    'total_eleve' => $total_eleve
                ),
                array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'));




                $current_price = (($ecoles * $classes)/10)*28 ; 


                $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_pmpro_membership_levels 
                SET initial_payment='%s' 
                WHERE name = %s",$current_price,'mairie'));


    }
?>
```

Comment: All of the dynamically generated inputs have the same `name` of `ecoles_name`. You'll need to name them differently, either with a number at the end, or use `ecoles_name[]` to make it an array.

Comment: but, then how I can implode them ??

Comment: You can't an implode a string, anyway. If you use `ecoles_name[]`, then it would exactly the way you have it in the code now.

Comment: Please can  you explain a little bit your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob so i may be wrong but:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < i_var; i++) {
 jQuery("#mairie_div_nom").prepend("Nom du l'ecole: <br> <input type='text' > name='ecoles_name' value='' required><br>");
            }
```

here you are echoing multiple inputs with the same name so, maybe you should do it like:

```
... input type='text' name='ecoles_name'"+ i +" value='' required><br>");
```

then in php you need to loop through the $_POST array and retrieve the ones that start with "ecoles_name".

EDIT:
If you were to, for example, get all school names in an array you could do something like:

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'ecoles_name') !== false){
     array_push($temp_ecoles_name,$value);
    }
    }
```

and then:

```
$ecoles_name=implode(', ',$temp_ecoles_name));
```